# Behavior of the OR clause in Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

My solr index contains documents which have a field named department. This field is a multivalue non-required int field. I want to construct a query whose result must be union of

- All the documents that do not contain the field department
- All the documents that contain the field department, but the values of the field are  restricted to a selected few.

I tried constructing the query that looks like so:

```
-department:* OR (department:* AND department:(100 OR 200))
```

This doesn't return any results. Whereas if I just just use

```
-department:*
```

or

```
department:* AND department:(100 OR 200)
```

, the query seems to work well. In short I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of OR clause in this context. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser)

Pure Negative Queries :-

> -field:[* TO *] finds all documents without a value for field

You can try :-

> q=-department:[* TO *] OR department:(100 OR 200)

Comment: Jayendra, thanks. -department:[* TO *] OR department:(100 OR 200) works. My issue is solved. But what's puzzling is A OR (A' AND B) doesn't return anything, while A , (A' AND B) independently return results. If you  go through the question again, you might understand it.

Comment: you can debug the query that is formed. You would know what the exact query was fired and on what fields.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, I think you can use [Solr grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing).

You can give something like,

```
&q=*&group=true&group.query=department:[100]&group.query=department:[200]&group.query=-department:[*]
```